# Как вычесть даты в Java?

Tags: java, android, дата, время

startDate: 2016-05-11 00:46;
endDate: 2016-05-12 12:26;
  в итоге должно быть: 1д 11ч 40мин

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

Answer (score 1):

Или можно монстра)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    Date dateS = format.parse("2016-05-11 00:46");
    Date dateE = format.parse("2016-05-12 12:26");

    long delt = dateE.getTime() - dateS.getTime();

    String result = String.format("%dд %dч %dмин",  
                                   delt / 86400000,  
                                   (delt % 86400000) / 3600000,  
                                   (delt % 3600000) / 60000);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Ответ: 1д 11ч 40мин
86400000 - соответственно дни.
Далее оперируем остатком от деления))

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться пакетом `java.time.*`, появившимся в Java 8:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-05-11 00:46", formatter);
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-05-12 12:26", formatter);

Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);

System.out.printf(
    "%dд %dч %dмин%n",
    duration.toDays(),
    duration.toHours() % 24,
    duration.toMinutes() % 60
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно перевести ваши даты в тип Date и присвоить к двум переменным, `startDate` и `endDate`

```
Date startDate = ...
Date endDate   = ...

long duration  = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
```